# Custom textfield showing a pickerview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a custom subclass of `UITextField` which manages a custom datePicker.

I use this code :

```
self.flatDatePicker = [[FlatDatePicker alloc] initWithParentView:pickerContainer];
_flatDatePicker.datePickerMode = FlatDatePickerModeMonthAndYear;
[self.flatDatePicker show];
self.inputView = _flatDatePicker;
```

**My problem**

When I touch my custom text field, the picker pops but my ViewController is moved up. My question is how to remove this movement ? I don't know if it is the normal behaviour of this, but I would like a solution for that.

[image: as you can see my viewcontroller is moved up.]

Comment: I think your keyboard is popped when you select the textfield. Have handled any keyboard events?

Comment: Are you using any KeyBoard event handler libraries? Like iKeyBoard etc...?

Comment: No keyboard library. But in my LoginViewController I use a method to moved up my viewController when I select the login or the password field. But this is not the same ViewController... (I use registerForKeyboardNotifications, keyboardWasShown...etc). Do you think I must to deregister to these notifications ?